# Froze or freeze bottle Exploding

Tags: thermodynamics, water, phase-transition, freezing

I kept a bottle in my freezer with full water overnight. When my mom took it out and put it in normal condition, it blasted after a few minutes. More surprisingly the bottle was made of aluminum. Pls, explain this.

Comment: I believe I read somewhere else on here of something where if something is chilled just under the right conditions (I think purity of the water mattered) ice crystals won't form. But if you disturb it they will form and it will spontaneously freeze. That might be related here.

Comment: Congratulations! https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/357805/

Comment: Could you please add some more details. What does blasting mean? Do you mean it exploded? Where did the aluminum bottle crack?

Comment: Yes, sustained temperatures of -35C or +35C will cause Pepsi cans to explode. I’ve seen it happen multiple times. The spontaneous freezing sounds like the best comment!

Comment: blasting means the bottle's bottom broke. it just came out now you can see through the bottle

Answer (score 1):

if left unperturbed and in a very clean container, a body of water will easily persist in the liquid state at temperatures below the freezing point. Then, when picked up and moved, the *supercooled* liquid will be sufficiently perturbed that nucleation sites will be created within the liquid and it will then spontaneously freeze all at once. It will then burst the container it is in.

Answer (score 0):

Frozen soda bottles explode better, this is because water expands when it freezes (the unusual property of water) which pushes the $CO_2$ from the bottle outward.  The union of pressurised $CO_2$gas trying to escape and ice filling a space too small for it is too much for the bottle, and this can make the bottle explode.

This works even without $CO_2$ gas, you fill up lets say a 500ml bottle. When it freezes the ice occupies more than 500ml hence pushing on the container, if this pushing amount is higher than the maximum tensile strain the bottle will break.